# How can I group data on the basis of date and hour in ms-sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have following data in my table activity_count

```
Activitydate        |count
2013-12-20:18:25:45  10
2013-12-20:18:23:40  20
2013-12-20:17:25:45   5
2013-12-20:17:25:45  10
2013-12-20:17:25:45  10
```

I want to get the total counts for each hour,ie the result should be following

```
Activitydate        |count
2013-12-20:18:00:00   30
2013-12-20:17:00:00   25
```

Comment: What is your mySQL version by the way? Or is it mySQL really because your title says "ms-sql"?

Comment: You appear to be using MS SqlServer - so you may want to remove the mysql tag.  You need to be using DATEPART(hour,<your date value>) to pull the hour number from <your date value>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `mySQL` try below:

```
SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(DATE(activitydate),10),' ',HOUR(activitydate),':00:00') as DateHour,
SUM(count) as TotalCount
FROM activity_count
GROUP BY DATE(activitydate),HOUR(activitydate)
```

See my [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20b270/4).

However, if `MSSQL` try this one:

```
SELECT CAST(CAST(activitydate as DATE) AS nvarchar(15))+' '+CAST(datepart(HOUR,activitydate) as CHAR(2))+':00:00' as DateHour,
SUM([count]) as TotalCount
FROM activity_count
GROUP BY CAST(CAST(activitydate as DATE) AS nvarchar(15)),DATEPART(HOUR, activitydate)
```

See MSSQL [Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fc896/1)

Comment: I'm writing an SQL Query and having the same issue. But while playing with the query on SQL Server 2012, it seems that the approach of:
...
 `GROUP BY 
DATEPART(year, activitydate), DATEPART(month, activitydate), DATEPART(day, activitydate),  DATEPART(hour, activitydate)` ...

is slightly quicker than 
`GROUP BY 
CAST(CAST(activitydate as DATE) AS nvarchar(15)),
DATEPART(HOUR, activitydate)`

on large datasets, I get for example, about 200ms difference, when running it on ~1,360,000 rows.

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
  select cast(cast(Activitydate as date) as datetime)+cast(datepart(hour,Activitydate),
  count(*)
   from activity_count 
  group by cast(cast(Activitydate as date) as datetime)+cast(datepart(hour,Activitydate)
```

Comment: you may need to enclose `cast(cast(Activitydate as date) as datetime)+cast(datepart(hour,Activitydate)` in bracket `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try `HOUR` function

```
 select 
Activitydate,        
count(*) as 'count'
from activity_count
GROUP BY HOUR(Activitydate)
```

Comment: when I ran this I am getting the error "Error code 195, SQL state S00010: 'HOUR' is not a recognized function name"

Comment: You're using MS Sql Server then...  so you use datepart(hour,Activitydate)

Comment: I think you need to take `sum(count)` instead of `count(*)` to get the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

[**HOUR(time)**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour)

```
 HOUR(time)
```

Returns the hour for time. The range of the return value is 0 to 23 for time-of-day values. However, the range of TIME values actually is much larger, so HOUR can return values greater than 23.